# calc mean/std/ci from column

Tags: r, statistics

is there a package to easily calculate for each specific n number, the mean/std/ci.
In example starting with the data:

```
> n = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,2,2,5,5,5,5,8,8,8,8)
> s = c(43,23,65,43,12,54,43,12,2,43,62,25,55,75,95,28,48,68,18)
> df = data.frame(n, s)
> df
   n  s
1  0 43
2  0 23
3  0 65
4  0 43
5  0 12
6  0 54
7  0 43
8  2 12
9  2  2
10 2 43
11 2 62
12 5 25
13 5 55
14 5 75
15 5 95
16 8 28
17 8 48
18 8 68
19 8 18
```

resulting as:

```
data
n mean std ci
0 40   ..  ..
2 30   ..  ..
5 63   ..  ..
8 41   ..  ..
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `dplyr` package.

Here's a code snippet. Note, I'm assuming you want to build the confidence interval using the standard normal approximation at the 95% level but you can make whatever choice you like.

```
n = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,2,2,5,5,5,5,8,8,8,8)
s = c(43,23,65,43,12,54,43,12,2,43,62,25,55,75,95,28,48,68,18)
df = data.frame(n, s)

  df %>%
  group_by(n) %>%
  summarise(mean = mean(s),
            std = sqrt(var(s)),
            lower = mean(s) - qnorm(.975)*std/sqrt(n()),
            upper = mean(s) + qnorm(.975)*std/sqrt(n()))

Source: local data frame [4 x 5]

  n     mean      std     lower    upper
1 0 40.42857 17.88721 27.177782 53.67936
2 2 29.75000 27.69326  2.611104 56.88890
3 5 62.50000 29.86079 33.236965 91.76303
4 8 40.50000 22.17356 18.770313 62.22969
```

Comment: you might want to be careful using the sd rather than the standard error for confidence intervals ...

Comment: @BenBolker: Hm -- I'm using sqrt(var(x)) but var(x) uses the n-1 as a denominator according to the help file. Should be ok no? Of course, this all presupposes normality... Totally agree with your Base R comment btw -- I just find dplyr a bit simpler to read -- but that's personal preference.

Comment: my point is that `sd(x)==sqrt(var(x))` (whether you use the unbiased estimator SSQ/(n-1) or the MLE estimator SSQ/n for variance) is the standard *deviation* not the standard *error*; the Normal CI uses +/- 1.96*SE

Comment: Oh -- sure -- as in for instance, the $SE(\bar{x}) = \frac{s}/\sqrt{n}$. Yep, I leave it to the OP to use the appropriate CI. I've modified my answer to reflect this. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

`dplyr` is nice, but not necessary. In base R:

```
 ## df() is built-in in R, avoid ...
 dd <- data.frame(n=rep(c(0,2,5,8),c(7,4,4,4)),
              s = c(43,23,65,43,12,54,43,12,2,43,
                  62,25,55,75,95,28,48,68,18))
 sumfun <- function(x) {
     m <- mean(x)
     s <- sd(x)
     se <- s/sqrt(length(x))
     c(mean=m,sd=s,lwr=m-1.96*se,upr=m+1.96*se)
 }
```

(or see `smean.cl.normal()`, `smean.cl.boot()`, etc. from the `Hmisc` package ...)

```
 res <- do.call(rbind,tapply(dd$s,dd$n,sumfun))
 res <- cbind(n=unique(dd$n),as.data.frame(res))
```

Or as pointed out by @thelatemail:

```
 res <- do.call(data.frame,aggregate(s ~ n, data=df, FUN=sumfun ))
```

You can easily package this into a function if you're going to use it on a regular basis.

For larger data sets/more complex transformations you can search SO for answers comparing solutions from the `dplyr`, `plyr`, `data.table`, `doBy` packages as well as base-R solutions using combinations of `tapply()`, `ave()`, `aggregate()`, `by()` ...

Comment: `aggregate` actually works okay for this too - `do.call(data.frame,aggregate(s ~ n, data=df, FUN=sumfun ))`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the advice everyone, I have taken a look into plyr and solved it:

```
n = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,2,2,5,5,5,5,8,8,8,8)
s = c(43,23,65,43,12,54,43,12,2,43,62,25,55,75,95,28,48,68,18)
dd = data.frame(n, s)

library(plyr)
data <- ddply(dd,.(n),function(dd) c(mean=mean(dd$s),
                                    std = sd(dd$s),
                                    se = sd(dd$s)/sqrt(length(dd$s)),
                                    lower = mean(dd$s)-qnorm(.975)*sd(dd$s)/sqrt(length(dd$s)),
                                    upper = mean(dd$s)+qnorm(.975)*sd(dd$s)/sqrt(length(dd$s))
                                    ))
```

resulting as:

```
    data
  n     mean      std        se     lower    upper
1 0 40.42857 17.88721  6.760731 27.177782 53.67936
2 2 29.75000 27.69326 13.846630  2.611104 56.88890
3 5 62.50000 29.86079 14.930394 33.236965 91.76303
4 8 40.50000 22.17356 11.086779 18.770313 62.22969
```

Will avoid df() in the future, thanks

Comment: why not use `summarise` as in @user1357015's answer??  (your answer is nearly identical to theirs except for the substitution of `plyr::ddply` for `dplyr::group_by` ...)

Comment: Not sure if you know this, but if you think someone answered your question, you should click the check mark to give them the points. All of your questions you seem to self-answer. This will give the responder extra points and makes them more interested in responding.

Comment: I have no experience with summarise, @user1357015 adviced dplyr package. Therefore my attention went straight for dplyr. Nonetheless, I am willing to take a look at Hmisc aswell and see what functions are available for my needs in future data analysis.

Comment: @DanielJansen: No problem, glad to help -- we were all new here at some point :-).

Answer (score 0):

### Update tidyr 1.0.0

Even though the solution by @user1357015 is totally fine, if you are a tidyverse fan like me, there is an elegant alternative:

The new [tidyr 1.0.0](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2019/09/tidyr-1-0-0/) contained a function that didn't get much attention but is very useful: `unnest_wider`.
With that, you can simplify the code to the following:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(n) %>% 
  nest(data = -"n") %>% 
  mutate(ci = map(data, ~ MeanCI(.x$s))) %>% 
  unnest_wider(ci)
```

which gives

```
# A tibble: 4 x 5
# Groups:   n [4]
      n data              mean lwr.ci upr.ci
  <dbl> <list>           <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1     0 <tibble [7 × 1]>  40.4  23.9    57.0
2     2 <tibble [4 × 1]>  29.8 -14.3    73.8
3     5 <tibble [4 × 1]>  62.5  15.0   110. 
4     8 <tibble [4 × 1]>  40.5   5.22   75.8
```